# Two arrays defining 2D coordinates, as array indices

Tags: matlab, arrays, indexing, octave

I have a 2D array, call it `A`.  I have two other 2D arrays, call them `ix` and `iy`. I would like to create an output array whose elements are the elements of `A` at the index pairs provided by `ix` and `iy`.  I can do this with a loop as follows:

```matlab
for i=1:nx
    for j=1:ny
        output(i,j) = A(ix(i,j),iy(i,j));
    end
end
```

How can I do this without the loop?  If I do `output = A(ix,iy)`, I get the value of A over the whole range of (ix)X(iy).

Comment: Be careful - you are using the ix array to provide the y coordinate and the iy array to provide the x. In MATLAB the first index is the y coordinate.
The same goes for yout output matrix - you are using the wrong limits for the for loops.

Comment: Good point, but it depends a bit on how he uses the data. If he doesn't care that displaying his matrix will show x up-down and y left-right, no fundamental problem with differing from that Matlab convention. But it sure is important to know, I agree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

A faster way is to use **linear indexing** directly without calling SUB2IND:

```
output = A( size(A,1)*(iy-1) + ix )
```

... think of the matrix A as a 1D array (column-wise order)

Comment: Wow, that is much faster!  Thank you.

Comment: @Jacob: Actually, I think `output` will end up the same size as `ix`.

Comment: Intelligent answer !
Thank you so much.

Answer (score 3):

This is the one-line method which is not very efficient for large matrices

```
reshape(diag(A(ix(:),iy(:))),[ny nx])
```

A clearer and more efficient method would be to use [sub2ind](http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/techdoc/ref/sub2ind.html). I've incorporated yuk's comment for situations (like yours) when `ix` and `iy` have the same number of elements:

```
newA = A(sub2ind(size(A),ix,iy));
```

Also, don't confuse `x` and `y` for `i` and `j` in notation - `j` and `x` generally represent columns and `i` and `y` represent rows.

Comment: Man, sorry for all the edits! I'm not thinking clearly today.

Comment: The sub2ind code can be just:    newA = A(sub2ind(size(A),ix,iy));